# Old novel about a woman kidnapped by her alien soulmate

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

This was an alien fiction love story based in the 80's or 90's about a woman who gets kidnapped by an alien because she's his soul mate and taken to his planet. Orgasm denial is apparently a form of punishment in their planet that's all I remember

Comment: Do you think it was written in the 80s and 90s, or that it was just set then?

Comment: Vaguely pornographic SF in the 80s immediately brings *Andrew J. Offutt* to mind, or more precisely his pen name *John Cleve*. One of the [Spaceways](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44009-spaceways) books?

Comment: Sounds like one of the Gor books by John Norman. No soul-mates, but a lot of women are slaves, and some are "love-slaves". The Goreans kidnap a lot of Earth women, as they are thought to be natural slaves.